# Did Joe Biden's Senate office retaliate against Tara Reade?

Tags: united-states, senate, joe-biden

Tara Reade [worked for Joe Biden's Senate office between December 1992 and August 1993](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/12/us/politics/joe-biden-tara-reade-sexual-assault-complaint.html), after which, she [voluntarily left the job](https://www.vox.com/2020/5/7/21248713/tara-reade-joe-biden-sexual-assault-accusation).  She recently claimed that he sexually assaulted her while she was working for him.  While definitive evidence for or against this claim is extremely difficult to obtain, a concurrent claim she has made is that Biden's office retaliated against her after she made some kind of complaint.

While journalists working with Reade have been able to uncover some documentation of her employment history (see above links), [other hurdles](https://www.npr.org/2020/05/04/850038361/senate-office-tells-biden-it-cannot-seek-tara-reade-records) have made it hard to piece together the facts.  Former interns for Biden have [confirmed aspects of retaliation claim](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2020/apr/24/joe-biden-sexual-assault-claim-tara-reade-deserves-to-be-heard-katie-halper).  Reade's mother [called into Larry King Live](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/25/politics/tara-reade-mom-larry-king/) shortly after Reade left the job to ask what a Senate staffer could do about "problems" with a senator.  While all we have is a recorded human voice which Reade personally identifies as that of her mother, there is corroborating evidence for this identification such as the timing of the call and the geographic origin of the call.

**Question:**  What other testimonial or documentary evidence exists regarding the circumstances of Reade's employment in the Senate, the nature of her responsibilities and how they may have changed over time, her relationship with supervisors and fellow employees, and any other facts which may be relevant to verifying Reade's claim of employer retaliation?

*EDIT NOTE:*  This edit reflects an attempt to address issues raised by fellow SE users that led to a vote to close.  I have attempted to make the question focus as closely as possible on objective and verifiable facts.

Comment: Good question, but impossible to answer until the records are unsealed.

Comment: @mbsq - I think the close reason on this is wrong, but it should still be closed.  I'd have voted for the "speculation / no public records" close reason.

Comment: @Bobson Wouldn’t that count as an answer, to document exactly is known and unknown about this? Also, couldn’t the answerability change tomorrow with some new disclosure? Journalists and scientists don’t refuse to ask questions whose answers are not yet known.  Better to keep the question open until further information is revealed.

Comment: @mbsq - Perhaps, but as [this meta post](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3098/2130) and [this one](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3210/2130) indicate, the community has decided that these are not currently on topic. Journalists and scientists investigate themselves - we don't. If something changes (some new news, for example), then someone can leave a comment and nominate the question for reopening, presuming that information doesn't render the question irrelevant.  If you disagree with the policy, open a meta thread about it.

Comment: @sjoerd Rethinking your position?

Comment: @mbsq Why would I? I haven't seen any records yet. Just a couple of people that confirm that something was going on back then (see e.g. the divorce filing by her then-husband). But what has happened, we'll never know without the records. And even with the records we might never know. So still impossible to answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd Look at the answer below...  The "unknowability thesis" is quite suspect.

Comment: @mbsq That answer has one person's recollections; There are various people with a different testimony. That makes it unanswerable, and not a good fit for this Q&A site.

Comment: @Sjoerd No, it is testimonial evidence.  The person is in a unique position to give the information he gave, and his identity and employment history are verifiable.  No one contradicted what he said except Reade herself and others who said she told them her story.  If you are going to discount testimonial evidence in general, then you're introducing unrealistic standards.  This is exactly the kind of relevant evidence for this kind of empirical question.

Comment: @mbsq It's still a "he says versus she says" situation.

Comment: @Sjoerd: You could also called it an issue of “she said, 74 people said.”  https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/what-74-former-biden-staffers-think-about-tara-reades-allegations

Answer (score 2):

[A former coworker disputes Reade’s claim](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/what-74-former-biden-staffers-think-about-tara-reades-allegations) and offers an alternative explanation:

> Ben Savage, who said his desk was next to Reade’s in the Biden mailroom, disputed her charge that she was forced out of her job in retaliation for a sexual harassment complaint she claims to have filed.
>
> Savage, who worked as the office’s systems administrator, overseeing computers and information processing, told the NewsHour that Reade was fired for her poor performance on the job, which he witnessed — not as retaliation for her complaints about sexual harassment.
>
> But according to Savage, Reade had been mishandling a key part of her job and an essential office task — processing constituent mail, something they worked on together. Savage said he recalls reporting these issues to his boss, deputy chief of staff Dennis Toner. After that, Savage said he began diminishing Reade’s duties, taking over some of her tasks and rerouting parts of the process to exclude her.
>
> “Of all the people who held that position, she’s the only one during my time there who couldn’t necessarily keep up or who found it frustrating,” said Savage, who worked in the office for three years, from 1993 to 1996.

The same former employee [states](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/05/19/politics/tara-reade-biden-allegation/index.html) that Reade told him she left the job for medical reasons.  Reade declined to comment on Savage’s testimony.

> Around the time of her departure, Savage said Reade "blamed her termination on her health issue -- that she thought she was being discriminated against for her health issue." Savage declined to share on the record for publication what Reade's stated medical issue was at the time.
>
> ...
>
> Reade told CNN she vaguely remembered Savage, but deferred questions about Savage's comments to Wigdor.